# How to call fake a constructor in Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Is it possible to call fake a constructor just like we do for functions?

My class is something like this

```
class testClass{
     constructor(){
        // to do class member init
        // how to avoid this method call.
        this.method();
     }

     private method() : weird class object {
         // to do method returns weird class object
     }
}
```

Is it possible to mock a constructor and avoid calling this.method().

i tried creating spy like this, but it did not work

```
jasmine.createSpy('testClass').and.callFake(() =>{})
```

Comment: I don't believe you can do that. You have to create a Mock Class.

Comment: Like MockClass and then provide it in providers

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't think you can highjack the constructor.

Comment: Ok sure, will try that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) to mock the module which has `testClass`.

E.g.

`TestClass.js`:

```js
class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    this.method();
  }

  method() {
    console.log('call method');
  }
}

module.exports = TestClass;
```

Then, we require and use `TestClass` in somewhere. `index.js`:

```js
const TestClass = require('./TestClass');

function main() {
  return new TestClass();
}

module.exports = main;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('61277026', () => {
  it('should call original TestClass', () => {
    const TestClass = require('./TestClass');
    const logSpy = spyOn(console, 'log').and.callThrough();
    const main = require('./');
    const actual = main();
    expect(actual).toBeInstanceOf(TestClass);
    expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('call method');
  });
  it('should call mocked TestClass', () => {
    const testClassInstance = jasmine.createSpy('testClassInstance');
    const TestClassSpy = jasmine.createSpy('TestClass').and.callFake(() => testClassInstance);
    const main = proxyquire('./', {
      './TestClass': TestClassSpy,
    });
    const actual = main();
    expect(actual).toBe(testClassInstance);
    expect(TestClassSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

unit results with coverage report:

```sh
Randomized with seed 34204
Started
(node:79855) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
call method
..


2 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.018 seconds
Randomized with seed 34204 (jasmine --random=true --seed=34204)
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 TestClass.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.test.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```